# G-oriented Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, group-actions, orientation

Let M be a compact manifold provided with an action of  a lie group G.

What is the meaning when we say  that M is G-oriented and if possible what is the intuition behind this notion?

Actually I'm reading an article on equivariant cohomology which say: "if M is G-oriented, integration over M gives us a map from $H^{-\infty}_G(M)$ (G-equivariant de Rham cohomology of M with generalized coefficients)to $C^{-\infty}(\mathfrak{g})^G$ (the subspace of generalized functions on $\mathfrak{g}$ which are invariant under the action of G endowed from the adjoint action)".

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We say that $M$ is $G$-oriented if $M$ is oriented and the $G$-action preserves the orientation of $M$.

If $M$ (not necessarily compact) is $G$-oriented, then we can talk about integrating (compactly supported) smooth equivariant form $\alpha\in\mathcal{A}^\infty_G(\mathfrak{g},M)=C^\infty(\mathfrak{g},\mathcal{A}(M))^G$
$$
\int_M\alpha\colon X\in\mathfrak{g}\mapsto\int_M\alpha(X)
$$
so get a map
$$
\int_M\colon \mathcal{H}^\infty_{G,c}(\mathfrak{g},M)\to C^\infty(M)^G
$$
where the differential defining the $G$-equivariant (compactly supported) cohomology group $\mathcal{H}^\infty_{G,c}$ is $(d_\mathfrak{g}\alpha)(X)=(d_M\alpha)(X)-i(X_M)(\alpha(X))$.  Now your article generalises this to distributions and do some more exotic things.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!  Could you please just  explain to me why  we could talk of integration only in the case when M is G-oriented, why this doesn't not work if M is just oriented and not G-oriented ?

Comment: First, note that $G_0$ always preserve the orientation, so the question is an involution in $G/G_0$ deciding to flip the orientation of $M$.  If that happens, there are no nonzero $G$-invariant top-degree form so $\int_M=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your help!